# Posição do Label - Swift IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

Boa noite pessoal. Como eu faço para deixar o label que esta informando o peso atual posicionado em baixo do cursor da barra de progresso ?

Para fazer essa barra de progresso estou usando o GradientSlider (https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/gradientslider)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já grato pela atenção.

Comment: Filipe, entendi que a barra de progresso você está utilizando a biblioteca mencionada, mas ao que parece, o *label* abaixo não faz parte dela, é isso? Se estou certo, como você está inserindo este *label*? Pelo *interface builder* ou diretamente no código? Pode demonstrar como o fez?

Comment: Olá @PauloRodrigues estou incluído pelo interface builder, e o label não faz parte da biblioteca.

Comment: Agora que li melhor sua pergunta, fiquei em dúvida. Você quer que o peso atual acompanhe o círculo branco conforme o usuário for deslizando com o dedo?

Comment: É mais ou menos isso, só que o círculo branco ele não é selecionável, o usuário não pode deslizar o mesmo.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues alguma ideia de como posso fazer o mesmo ?

Answer (score 0):

Simulei uma possível forma de fazer isso usando o UISlider e o método thumbRectForBounds. Contudo, verifiquei que o GradientSlider não possui um método direto para pegar o tamanho e posição do thumb. Sugiro que tu dê uma olhada ano código do GradientSlider, na propriedade _thumbLayer. Você terá que expor essa propriedade para expor o tamanho do thumb, e dai você poderá usar a técnica que descrevo no código abaixo.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueLabel: UILabel!

    private var displayValue : String {
        get {
            let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
            formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
            return formatter.stringFromNumber(slider.value)!
        }
    }

    @IBAction func moveLabel() {
        let thumbBounds = slider.thumbRectForBounds(view.bounds, trackRect: slider.trackRectForBounds(view.bounds), value: slider.value)

        let offsetXPercentage = (slider.value - slider.minimumValue) / (slider.maximumValue - slider.minimumValue)
        valueLabel.frame.origin.x = thumbBounds.origin.x + slider.frame.origin.x - slider.frame.origin.x * CGFloat(offsetXPercentage)
        valueLabel.text = "\(displayValue)"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Já fiz algo parecido, mas o Slider podia ser movido pelo usuário. Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
  [...]

  self.updateHintForSlider(sender)
}

func updateHintForSlider(sender: UISlider) {
  var frame = self.hintLabel.frame
  frame.origin.x = thumbCenterOnSlider(sender) - (frame.size.width / 2)
  self.hintLabel.frame = frame

  self.hintLabel.text = NSString(format: "%.0f", sender.value) as String
}

func thumbCenterOnSlider(slider: UISlider) -> CGFloat {
  let sliderRange = slider.frame.size.width - slider.currentThumbImage!.size.width
  let sliderOrigin = slider.frame.origin.x + (slider.currentThumbImage!.size.width / 2.0)

  let sliderValueToPixels = CGFloat((slider.value - slider.minimumValue) / (slider.maximumValue - slider.minimumValue)) * sliderRange + sliderOrigin

  return sliderValueToPixels
}
```

- O método `sliderValueChanged:` é chamado quando o valor do Slider for alterado.
- O método `thumbCenterOnSlider:` obtém o centro da "bolinha branca" (chamada "thumb")
- O método `updateHintForSlider:` atualiza a posição e o texto da label que, no seu caso, informa o peso atual (`self.hintLabel`)

PS:

A label é iniciada assim:

```
var frame = self.slider.frame
frame.size.width = 50
frame.size.height = 50
frame.origin.x = thumbCenterOnSlider(self.slider) - (frame.size.width / 2)
frame.origin.y = 20

self.hintLabel = UILabel(frame: frame)
```

Comment: Ola @BrunoSerrano, seu método funciona mais no meu caso ele infelizmente não funciona, mesmo assim muito obrigado pela ajuda e atenção.